# How to generate a random operator, put it in string, and evaluate the string

Tags: go

I'm trying to build an equation that takes random operators.

3 x 5 x 8 x 2

where x represents either a +, -, / * operator.

2nd question: if the equation is a string, can golang evaluate the answer?

(this question is for this problem http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/1k7s7p/081313_challenge_135_easy_arithmetic_equations/
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating a random operator is straightforward:

```
    rand.Seed(int64(time.Now().Unix()))
    op := "+-/*"[rand.Intn(4)]
    fmt.Printf("%c\n", op)
```

(that's `math/rand`)

Evaluating simple expressions in the format suggested is also easy. Here is a simplistic, inefficient, and fragile way of doing it:

```
expr := strings.Fields("4 * 8 / 2 * 3")
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", expr)

do := func(i int, op func(a, b int) int) {
    ai, err := strconv.Atoi(expr[i-1])
    check(err)
    bi, err := strconv.Atoi(expr[i+1])
    check(err)
    expr[i-1] = strconv.Itoa(op(ai, bi))
    expr = append(expr[:i], expr[i+2:]...)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", expr)
}

for _, ops := range []string{"*/", "+-"} {
    for i := 0; i < len(expr); i++ {
        if strings.Contains(ops, expr[i]) {
            switch expr[i] {
            case "*": do(i, func(a, b int) int { return a*b })
            case "/": do(i, func(a, b int) int { return a/b })
            case "+": do(i, func(a, b int) int { return a+b })
            case "-": do(i, func(a, b int) int { return a-b })
            }
            i -= 2
        }
    }
}

fmt.Println(expr[0])
```

(runnable on http://play.golang.org/p/pITy4SgXaA)

Making it not break down with improper expressions and handle non-ints is left as an exercise for the reader.

As a side note, these kinds of challenges are generally meant as entertainment for the developer. Asking here means you're transferring that fun to somebody else.

Comment: Agreed, about it as entertainment. I'm new to Go, and thought it was an interesting question, something other people would find useful too. But yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Go does not have an eval function like Perl or JavaScript. So if you want to evaluate an equation from a string, you will need to write the code to parse it and evaluate it yourself.

(The reason for this is that Go is a compiled language, and it does not put a copy of the compiler into every program. It is much easier to add an eval function to an interpreted language than to a compiled one.)